# How to store one of two constants in a value, where the constants share traits?

Tags: rust

Depending on configuration I need to select either `stdout` or `sink` once, and pass the results as an output destination for subsequent output call.s

My Java and C++ experience tell me that abstracting away from the concrete type is wise and makes room for future design changes. This code however won't compile:

```
let out = if std::env::var("LOG").is_ok() {
    std::io::stdout()
} else {
    std::io::sink()
};
```

Stating...

```
`if` and `else` have incompatible types
```

What is the Rust-o-matic way of solving this?

Comment: use a enum or dynamic dispatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic dispatch using trait objects is probably what you need:

```
use std::io::{self, Write};
use std::env;

fn get_output() -> Box<dyn Write> {
    if env::var("LOG").is_ok() {
        Box::new(io::stdout())
    } else {
        Box::new(io::sink())
    }
}

let out = get_output();
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach from Peter's answer is probably what you need, but it does require an extra allocation. (Which probably doesn't matter in the least in this case, but could matter in other scenarios.) If you are only passing `out` *downward*, i.e. as argument to functions, you can avoid the allocation by using two variables to store the different outputs:

```
let (mut stdout, mut sink);
let out: &mut dyn Write = if std::env::var("LOG").is_ok() {
    stdout = std::io::stdout();
    &mut stdout
} else {
    sink = std::io::sink();
    &mut sink
};
// ...proceed to use out...
```

Comment: Kudos to user4815162342 who avoids the heap allocation, at the expense of keeping both `stdout` and `sink` on the stack.